# c++ com object over rpc

Tags: c++, com, rpc

I have a desktop application that communicates to c++ com object locally, however now i have to move that com object to server(somewhere else) but the application will remain there locally. That com objects communicates two way, receive data from desktop app and send events as well.

so is there any way to use rpc or any other technique to communicate to com object placed/installed on server, when the application will be running on client machine? I need to do it Without changing the complete com code?

There could be an approach to use the same dummy com object on client and in the implementation i can do manual calls over the server com, but it would require re implementation on client side for 100s of functions.

As i am new to c++, being a c# .Net developer i am not exactly sure there is something else in c++ that can help me to get it achieved.

Comment: You can use COM+ component service https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679164.aspx. Your component would then be hosted by a surrogate process (so it will not be in-process but out-of-process). You can try that pretty quickly, it's just a matter of configuration, even on the same machine (out-of-process). However, if the COM component (dll) was not designed for that (proper marshaling, performance, security, etc.), it may not work, require some extra work, or even a complete rewrite. The fact events are used don't smell good to be frank.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but i cannot host the dll on client machine. even if its running out of process. it needs to be hosted on VM(independent server).

Comment: I was looking into the com code, and in the entry point it is using standard api call "DllGetClassObject" what about i reroute the call on the server through rpc? will that work?

Comment: I was talking about the client machine for your own *testing*. If it does not work out-of-process on the client machine, it will never work on a server. DllGetClassObject is totally unrelated to all that. You should read the links I gave you as a start, books, etc. enhance your knowledge of COM; you don't seem know enough of COM today to solve this by yourself - no offense.

Comment: [DCOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Component_Object_Model) is designed to do what you describe, though I don't know how well it works over the Internet when firewalls are involved.

Comment: I don't think either the client or the server application code should call DllGetClassObject() themselves.  Rather, the COM infrastructure calls it in the process of satisfying a client attempt to instantiate the server, i.e. via [CoCreateInstance()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686615(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I think it's unusual for the remote server to be implemented as a DLL (a COM server can be implemented in an exe instead), but apparently it's possible using an exe [DLL surrogate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695225(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: yes but if i do the manual call like i have mentioned in the description "There could be an approach to use the same dummy com object on client and in the implementation i can do manual calls over the server com, but it would require re implementation on client side for 100s of functions."

To call the server i can use webapi/wcf hosted on the server and api will call those server dll functions? will that approach work?

Comment: When a client talks to a COM object outside its own process, it makes method calls on a _proxy_ object that implements the same interface as the server object.  The proxy marshals each call over IPC or RPC to the server object.  The proxy code is generated by the IDL compiler.  You do not need to re-implement anything.